# Writing batch file to run .exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I have created a C# console application with Visual studio 2010. I would like to achieve running my program without human interact and even without the opening of the visual studio.
Manually to do so will be navigating to pathName\programName\programName\bin\Debug\ and double click the application file programName.exe

But how can i do this automated? with no opening of VS?

Thanks,
Lain

Comment: Why dont you right click on the exe and choose `Send To > Desktop as shortcut`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open notepad, put in 1 line:

```
pathName\programName\programName\bin\Debug\programName.exe
```

Save as `Runner.bat`

Run "Runner.bat" however you like.

However unless you're specifying any extra parameters, or anything else that affects execution of the program this is completely redundant.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However is it possible not to show the command prompt?

Comment: See my final paragraph. If you just run the executable (you can setup Windows Task Scheduler to do this, instead of pointing it to the batch file, point it to the .exe - you can copy the files from the Debug or Release folder to a more convenient location if you want, they do not require Visual Studio to run) directly without using a batch file you might avoid getting a command prompt. I don't know what you're trying to do but I don't think a batch file is entirely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
title LainsAutoRun

ECHO "Running Application"

"YourApp.exe" 

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file name is C:\run.exe, you can run it from the batch file as follow:

Create a batch file myfile.bat
Paste this inside your batch file "C:\run.exe"
Save

Now running this batch file will run your exe.

To automate this, add a task into Windows Scheduler. You can specify how often you want to automatically run the batch file or exe.

BTW, 
To run this exe one time without opening VS, simply type C:\run.exe at the command prompt.

More information on windows scheduler is [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)